# Vuejs sending a GET request with a method

Tags: javascript, html, rest, vue.js, get

I was trying to send a `GET` request using vue, but now I'm trying to extend it's functionality. I would like to bind sending the request to the form's submit button, and also pass a param from textfield in the form I've created.

HTML

```html
<html>
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Bookstyle.css"> 
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <a href="#contact">Cart</a>
        <a href="#about">Orders</a>
        <a href="#profil">Profile</a>
        <form id="searchbar">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search"> </input> // the input I want to send as paramValue
            <input id="sendButton" type="submit" value="search"> // the button to trigger sending the request
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="app"></div>
</body>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="./script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

JS

```js
const app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        paramValue: "test", // the parameter currently bound like this for test purposes
        bookResponse: [],
    },
        mounted() {
            axios
                .get("http://localhost:8080/Books/getByParam/{param}", {
                    params: {
                        param: `${this.paramValue}`
                    }   
                })
                .then(response => (this.bookResponse = response.data))
    },
    template: `
        <div id = "displayReturnedValue">
            <p v-for="book in bookResponse" style="font-size:20px;">
                Title:{{book.title}} 
                Publisher:{{book.publisher}}
                Price:{{book.price}} 
                Availability:{{book.availability}}
                Category:{{book.categoryid.category}}
                Author:{{book.authorid.firstname}} {{book.authorid.lastname}}
            </p>
        </div>`
})
```

Comment: If you've been able to write all that so far, I'm suprised that you're struggling to do an `onClick`/`onSubmit` ? Create a new function that performs what ever needs to be done, then trigger that new method it by putting an on a onclick/onsubmit https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html

Comment: What I'm finding most troublesome is to wrap my form into the vue element since the template would just override my html.

Comment: You don't really need a proper `<form>` since Javascript is handling the submission/request via AJAX. So I would get rid of that personally

Comment: why don't you move all you searchBar code to vue template ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply add an `onclick` listener and bind it with a method:

```html
<input id="sendButton" type="submit" value="search" @click="sendRequest()>
```

```js
methods: {
    sendRequest() {
        if (this.$refs.input.value) {
            axios.get("http://localhost:8080/Books/getByParam/{param}", {
                params: {
                    param: this.$refs.input.value
                }   
            })
            .then(response => (this.bookResponse = response.data))
        }
    }
}
```

As for the param, you can simply keep track of the value using `$ref`. Although there are many alternatives.

```html
<input ref="input" type="text" placeholder="Search" />
```

The form is only submitted if the input has a value.

Comment: I see how this is done, but how would I bind the div containing my buttons to the Vue instance?